# Excel Macro - not running all Subs

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following macro and I'm trying to achieve the following:

1. Delete the first 3 lines
2. Autofit each column
3. Rename some columns and delete the remaining.

It seems to only run the first routine of deleting the first 3 lines and nothing else. I am very new to Macro's so it seems I'm missing something vital to run all Subs?

Option Explicit

```
Sub sbDeleteARowMulti()
  Rows("1:3").Delete
End Sub

Sub sbChangeColumnWidthMulti()
  Columns("A:Z").AutoFit
End Sub


Sub RenDelCols()
  Dim vCols As Variant
  Dim vNames As Variant
  Dim iCols As Integer
  Dim iCol As Integer
  Dim wks As Worksheet
  Dim i As Integer



  'define the worksheet
  Set wks = Worksheets("timesheets2")
  'Cols in Receiving to be renamed
  vCols = Array(2, 9, 14, 15, 16, 19) 'Cols A,L,N,Q,X,Y
  'Names from Order to rename them to
  vNames = Array("Project", "Supervisor", "Employee", "Status", "Date", "Time")

  With wks
    iCols = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For iCol = iCols To 1 Step -1
      i = 0
      'check if col number is one to change
      On Error Resume Next
      i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(iCol, vCols, 0)
      On Error GoTo 0
      If i = 0 Then
        'column is not in list, delete it
        .Columns(iCol).EntireColumn.Delete
      Else
        'col is in list, rename it
        .Cells(1, iCol).Value = vNames(i - 1)
      End If
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The other two subs never get called, so of course they aren't executed.

Comment: how you run your code?.. combine all sub into one and then try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a sub inside another sub you only need to do:

```
Call Subname()
```

The brackets are even optional if there are no parameters to pass.

So you could edit your first sub like this:

```
Sub sbDeleteARowMulti()
    Rows("1:3").Delete
    Call sbChangeColumnWidthMulti
    Call RenDelCols
End Sub
```